# Recently moved back to the US after several years in Europe - why do some site still show prices in Euros?

Tags: internet, localization

I just moved back to the US after spending 3 years in Europe.  I have visited a couple commercial sites (e.g., Amazon.com) pushing me towards their French sites.  I have also seen some international commercial sites displaying their prices in Euros rather than Dollars.

Why does that happen, and what can I do so that my location is properly understood as US by the websites I visit?

Comment: Is your timezone set correctly to your current location? Not sure if that has any affects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am guessing you need to clear your cache and cookies. They may be logged in there, and are now still reading them as you being in that country.

Also make sure to synchronize with a time server - you may not have updated properly. Although this seems least likely to me

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  What do you mean by "synchronize with a time server"?

Comment: On windows, right click on the time in the bottom right corner. Here is an image guide for it. http://i54.tinypic.com/20jk6ck.png

Comment: No problem. Did any of these answers help your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Check your time zone settings on the clock.

Comment: Could you clarify how to do this and how it might help please? Your answer isn't very useful in its current state, but I do think this could help solve the problem if you provide some more information!

Comment: Its the same answer as above. When you moved I suspect you just changed the time on the clock to match the local time. Many websites detect the timezone setting on the machine you are using and display information according to that. In Amazon, you probably need to change your account. Double Click on the clock and check your time zone.

Comment: if it is the same answer above, then you should delete it, as a duplicate answer isn't very useful.